# If function - equal/different/blank

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula

I'm trying to write an formula that will give me the following result:
IF H1=H2, write "OK", if they are different, write "NO", if H1 is blank, then become blank too.
I tried like this:

```
=IF(H1=H2;"OK";"NO";IF(H1="";""))
```

And it says I've entered too many arguments for this function.

Any advice?

Answer (score 3):

You added an extra `;`, try this:

```
=IF(H1="";"";IF(H1=H2;"OK;"NO"))
```

Answer (score -1):

Solved like this

```
=IF(H1="","",IF(H1=H2,"OK","NO"))
```

Thankyou everyone

Comment: Instead of posting an answer that is identical, except the local setting for the delimiter, you should mark @Bob__ as correct.  He gave you the answer based on your questions local settings.  You mark an answer correct by clicking on the green check mark by the answer.